# Spring beans injected into JSF Managed Beans

Tags: spring, jsf, configuration

Problem Description: My injected Spring bean defined as a Managed-Property to a JSF backing bean is not being instantiated. Its always coming up null when I retreive the Managed-Bean.

I have been fighting with this all day and it seems that JSF Managed Bean just won't read out of the applicationContext from Spring. I can manually pull out the bean by using the FacesContext in a backing bean and it finds the bean but when I try and inject it through the FacesConfig it always comes out null. I included my steps below how I integrated it. Any suggestions?

#### Configuration

Icefaces 1.85

JSF 1.2  (through ice faces servlet)

Spring 3.0

Websphere 7.5 ( Which is eclipse 3.5  I think )

### Web.xml Configuration Changes

#### Spring Context Loader Listener

```
    <listener>
    <display-name>SpringListener</display-name>
    <icon>
        <small-icon>small.gif</small-icon>
        <large-icon>large.gif</large-icon>
    </icon>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

#### Context Config

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/SpringConfig/SpringHelloWorld.xml
    </param-value> 
</context-param>
```

### FacesContext Changes

#### Variable Resolver - AKA The Glue

`<application><variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver></application>`

#### Managed Bean

```
   <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>testData</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>src.test.TestData</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>spring3HelloWorldBean</property-name>
        <value>#{spring3HelloWorldBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

#### Spring.xml Config

```
<bean id="spring3HelloWorldBean" class="src.test.Spring3HelloWorld" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all and I think this your problem that DelegatingVariableResolver is deprecated in all JSF version after 1.1 and you are using 1.2 so please use this following configuration.

```
<application> 
<el-resolver> 
org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver 
</el-resolver> 
</application>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try tomorrow first thing. I did try using a el-resolver but I don't think it was that class. I'll update tomorrow. Cheers for the help.

Comment: @Bozho and @danny.lesnik it didn't seem to work. A key piece information I left out is that I am also using Icefaces 1.8 which uses jsf 1.2 . Not sure if that makes a difference. When using the the contextLoader Listener, it doesn't need any kind of "load" priority like you would set with the contextLoadServlet?

Comment: @haju - did you try my suggestion with annotations? Does it work?

Comment: @Bozho what spring jar has the Inject annotation? I added all the spring jars onto the build path and it can't seem to find it. 

I don't have to use the Controller annotation in order to use the inject one correct? I can still define a jsf managed bean and within that class for the bean use the inject annotation for spring beans right?

Comment: it's jsr-330, but you can use `@Autowired` instead - it's the same

Comment: @Bozho ya I tried it but didn't seem to inject it. As seen below where spring3HelloWorldBean is the name of the bean id in the spring.xml

 @Autowired
 Spring3HelloWorld spring3HelloWorldBean;

Comment: @danny.lesnik and @Bozho I fixed the original problem of the injecting not working. I had a blasted typo above in my managed property. I had the class defined as the value.

Comment: I like the approach though of the @Injected. It seems to be that is the same thing as using a JSF managed property for a Spring bean except you bypass the facescontext configuration and less chance of typo's.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` you can benefit even more from spring by using annotations. So instead of defining your managed bean in xml, just do:

```
@Controller
public class FooBean {
    @Inject
    private SpringService service;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Does that mean I wouldn't have a need to define the bean at all in the facescontext? Would the same @Inject also apply to injecting another managed bean?  I assume so.

Comment: @haju - yes. All managed beans would live in the spring context. (You'll just have to include their package in the `component-scan`)